# Bugs after baking textures

Tags: rendering, materials, baking

I don't know how to fix the texture. The problem mainly occurs after loading the baked texture into the blender. In EU5, the problem is less visible, and in substance painter everything looks as it should.

I tried to fix the problem by compacting the uv mesh on the problem spot. It's better, but the problem persists. This is my first UV mesh.

Do you have any ideas on how to fix it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Would be helpful to share a problematic part of mesh via https://blend-exchange.com btw isnt it possible you accidentally moved some vertices? SP screen looks like different mesh.

Comment: blend-exchange.com/b/YsKQvBE3

Mesh has not been modified. The SP is the same model, it may look different due to a different perspective.

Comment: your screens doesnt use normal map texture, also you didnt append normal map texture into your file so hard to say ...